# Discord Bot: Per-Guild variables that don't reset on reloading

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm really new to discord bot coding and I stumbled across a problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around, nor is searching the web of any help so far. So I thought I'd ask :)

What I want, is a variable that is different for each discord 'guild' (server), and that changes with a command. This variable is the prefix (I want it to be customisable for each server). Now my problem is that every time the bot reloads, the prefix resets back to the default prefix :(

**Code:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { token, defaultPrefix } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const today = new Date();

var prefix = {}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`[${today}] Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
});

client.on('message', msg =>
    {
        let id = msg.guild.id

        if (prefix[id] == undefined) {
            prefix[id] = defaultPrefix;
        };


        if (msg.content.StartsWith(prefix[id] + 'prefix')) {
            if (msg.content.split(" ")[1] && !msg.content.split(" ")[2]) {
                msg.channel.send(`Successfully changed prefix!`)    
                prefix[id] = msg.content.split(" ")[1]
            }
        }
    }
);

client.login(token);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference this bot is written in Javascript, so when searching for references looking up "how to store data outside my application In Javascript" will get you a lot farther than searching discord bot.

As per your question, all variables are stored in the ram and is cleared once the application closes. In order to get persistent data you will have to store it externally and access it. You could do this by writing to a txt file or a Json, but this often can corrupt.
You're best bet is to start by building an sqlite database and connecting your application to it to store and access data.

Here is a full tutorial on how to create a database and some starting tables, and how to connect a discord.js bot to said database.

[link](https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/sqlite-based-points-system)